# Finding the position of some substrings in a string

Tags: haskell

After a bit of hoogle-ing I came up with this:

```
import Data.List
substrPos xs str = map (\x -> findIndex (isPrefixOf x) $ tails str) xs
```

That should give me a list of indices that represent the first appearance in `str` of every string in `xs`.

E.g.:

```
Prelude Data.List> substrPos ["Foo", "Bar"] "FooBar"
[Just 0,Just 3]
```

The question is how can I write it more idiomatic, maybe I can lose the lambda?
Maybe somehow (function composition?) remove the parens enclosing `isPrefixOf x`?
Maybe write it in point free style?

How should I go about thinking of these things?

PS: The only modification I could come up with (after first writing the function) is the removal of parens from `tails xs` by function application.

Comment: You may want to see if this would get be more appropriate and get more attention at [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks, I will if needed.

Comment: Although you could write it several other ways (in addition to point free, you could e.g. go the other way and use a list comprehension), I think your code is plenty idiomatic enough. Although if your argument order were the other way around, I'd have recommended losing the explicit `xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always install the [pointfree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) tool and check it for yourself and try to understand the resultant code.

Pointfree tool gives me the following result:

```
map (($ tails str) . findIndex . isPrefixOf) xs
```

Although you should note that pointfree style is not always idiomatic. Some people consider it as unreadable and [pointless](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Problems_with_pointfree).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that tool, I think I understood its result. Indeed the result may be much harder to read, but I'm doing this for my own exercise with haskell.