# Haskell Program to find a Sub-string within a string

Tags: string, haskell, option-type

I want to write a Haskell function with this type signature:

```
findStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
```

`findStr pat str` will try to find the sub-string `pat` within the string `str`. If successful, it will return `Just n`, where `n` is position of `pat` within `str`.

`Example:`

```
findStr "abc" "abcdefg" -- returns Just 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349038/finding-the-position-of-some-substrings-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
findStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
findStr pat str = findStrHelp pat str 0
  where
    findStrHelp _ [] _ = Nothing
    findStrHelp pat s@(x:xs) n
      | pat == (take (length pat) s) = Just n
      | otherwise = findStrHelp pat xs (n+1)
```

`findStr` calls a helper function which keeps track the current index. `findStrHelp` then just needs to check if the entered pattern is equal to the next substring of the length of the pattern. If it is, it returns `Just <index>` and else it checks the next substring. If it encounters an empty list it fails and returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Sincere thanks for the assistance with this approach. I am really new to haskell and this really helps. I used this approach given and can now see the logic in what I'm doing.

Sincere thanks for the clarity.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, also using recursion:

```
findStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
findStr sub s
          | length sub > length s      = Nothing
          | take (length sub) s == sub = Just 0
          | otherwise                  = fmap (+1) $ findStr sub $ drop 1 s
```

There are two termination conditions: either the substring is bigger than the string, in which case `Nothing` is returned (and we stop recursing) or the substring matches the beginning of the string, in which case we stop recursing because we have a match (we return `Just 0`).

In case none of the termination condition is reached, we count where we're at and we recurse by dropping the first character of the string.

Comment: Hi, I am truly grateful for the time you have taken in assisting me. As a newbie, I am only familiar the common argument structure and so can see the logic in the approach you've specified, but my limited haskell vocabulary impedes on my understanding of the "fmap" call. Currently, I donot fully understand why you've used "fmap" but at this point in time, I believe it is used to traverse the array of characters in the given string?

I will have to research further on this though.

But many thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: @yamis7190: I suggest you Google for the (very simple) tutorial, with pictures, called: *"Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures"*: it is really easy to follow. Basically you wanted to return a *Maybe Int* (which is good), so *findStr* returns that: *fmap (+1) (Just 1)* returns *(Just 2)*.  *fmap (+1) Nothing* returns *Nothing*.  Which is what you want.  *fmap* here is simply used to add 1 to a *Maybe*.

Comment: Thank you. I've done exactly that and all seems clear now. Truly appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
findStr x y
           | (length $ filtered x y) == 0 = Nothing
           | otherwise = Just $ fst $ head $ filtered x y

filtered :: String -> String -> [(Int, String)]
filtered x y = filter (\(p,q) -> q == x) $ zip [0..(1 + lenY - lenX)] [take lenX $ drop n y | n <- [0..(lenY - lenX)]]
                where lenX = length x
                      lenY = length y
```

`filtered` is a helper function which uses zip to create a list of key-value pairs of index and corresponding substring of length equal to that of `pat`, and then gets those pairs which match `pat`. `findStr` then returns `Nothing` if the above list is empty i.e. no match found, or `Just k` where k is the first match index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this alternative approach. As a newbie to Haskell, I am not really familiar with how to go about structuring my arguments, nor the variety of approaches that I can employ in solving my problems. This alternative really helps.

Cheers!

Comment: No worries. But I think you should go for either of the 2 approaches above, because mine seems to be much more bloated and inefficient.

Comment: Yes I'll do that. Even though the approach you used is totally new to me, running it a few times in hugs, along with the other alternatives given, has really helped me understand the logic behind your choice of algorithm, hence the arguments structure.

Many thanks.