# Position of a sublist in a list haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, sublist

Ok so I'm trying to write a function that determines the position of a string in another string if the first one is a sublist of the second. Say there's a string like "pie" and another one like "applepie", the function would return 5, since the first letter of "pie" is at the position 5 in the string "applepie"

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do that?

Comment: Guess what, we do have an idea how to do that! But surely, _you_ have an _idea_ as well, how about telling us what you've thought of and where you have problems in getting it to work?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I just started working with haskell so I don't know a lot, but I did a function with list comprehension that takes the position of a letter in the string "applepie" when that letter is the same as the first letter of "pie", but it wont work cause if the strings were "church" and "igotochurch" it would return 2 positions, 6 and 10, when it's supposed to return only 6.

Comment: You can use `==` on entire lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908894/haskell-program-to-find-a-sub-string-within-a-string/24909512#24909512) question. It was asked (and answered) a few days ago and covers **exactly** your problem.

My solution:

```
findStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
findStr pat str = findStrHelp pat str 0
  where
    findStrHelp _ [] _ = Nothing
    findStrHelp pat s@(x:xs) n
      | pat == (take (length pat) s) = Just n
      | otherwise = findStrHelp pat xs (n+1)
```

To get this code without maybe, just remove the `findStrHelp _ [] _` line and change the `Just n` to `n`. Also change the `Maybe Int` in the type signature to `Int`.

Comment: @TherreFx I'm not familiar with the Maybe class, but in that case, I already know that that first string is for sure a sublist of the second because I wrote a function to check, so I'm guessing it is not necessary to use Maybe class.

Comment: @emic I added instructions how to change the code so you do'nt need a maybe but **I strongly suggest** looking into Haskell's ``Maybe`` as it is core to the language in situations like this.

Comment: what does s@(x:xs) does?

Comment: @emic ``s@(x:xs)`` is an as pattern which basically enables you to use ``s`` as a shortcut for ``(x:xs)``

Comment: just to make sure I understood how that function works, if the first "part" of str is equivalent to pat, then it will return 0, if not it will add +1 and evaluate the function again for the tail of str. Is that correct?